# Relational Links in Access tables

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database that contains 13 tables.  The data in the tables are numbers.  I would like to be able to relate specific fields in the tables and sum the totals for all of the tables together.
For instance, I have fields for patient information completed in several of the tables the number in the field is the number of patients who completed the form.  Each table represents a different facility.  The total would represent the number of patients from all of the facilities who completed the form so that I have a grand total.

I'm not sure about how to go about linking the tables.
Thanks,
Gale

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These tables do not have relationships - they have the same kind of data, not related data (such as relating Customers to Orders). This is not correct data structure. Should not have a separate table for each facility. Should be one table with another field to ID the facility. Otherwise, UNION query these tables into a single dataset should be in first place.

```
SELECT ID, F1, F2, F3, "Fac01" AS Facility FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ID, F1, F2, F3, "Fac02" FROM Table2
...
UNION SELECT ID, F1, F2, F3, "Fac13" FROM Table13;
```

Then use that dataset in subsequent queries, such as GROUP BY or CROSSTAB.